# How can I include :not method jquery in the below code

Tags: jquery

I am invoking one popup window when user clicking on table row...

[image]

The entire row is click-able area to invoke the popup window.  The code I have written for the stuff is:

```
$('.assignPanel tbody.contentRows tr').on('click', function () {
            $('.sliderPanel1').show();                         
        });
```

It is working very fine.  No issues.

The issue i am facing is, when user clicks on links available in the row, lets say 'Gary Horsley' where i have marked blue color border, the popup window should not get opened up.

And also, when clicking on the 'Gary Horsley' link, have to open another kind of popup window.  How can I do that?  I heard that ':not' method will help to get this work done.  I tried but I messed up.  Could anyone of help me out in this regard?

Comment: this is not sufficient code. Please write html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stopPropagation in child click elements click and write the required code to open popup:

```
$(".assignPanel tbody.contentRows tr *").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //show another pop up
});
```

Comment: jquery all selector http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/. if you want to prevent on any partical element then write that elements selector instead of *.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by Milind Anantwar looks cleaner, but here is another way to do this, using `:not` -

```
$('.assignPanel tbody.contentRows tr :not("a")').on('click',function(e) {
      $('.sliderPanel1').show();   
});
```

Please test once. I am ignoring all anchor elements (you may need to change what is inside the :not() to particular anchor elements). This should work if your anchor elements are direct children of the tr.